# Slice every item except every nth

Tags: python, tensorflow, multidimensional-array, tensor, tensor-indexing

In tensorflow it is possible to select every nth item with the slicing notation `[::n]`.

But how to do the opposite? I want to select every item except every nth.

For example:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

`a[2::3]` would result in `[3, 6]`

Now I would like to have the opposite: `[1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8]`

*The array above is just an example. A solution should work for bigger matrices of the dimension [batch, width, height, channels] in tensorflow. The selection is only done on the channels. Also my matrix contains real values that are non unique. I will also not be able to reshape it further down than to two dimensions ( `[batch, channels]` )*

Comment: As the answers show you can construct a list (or boolean mask) of the items to keep.  The resulting selection will be a copy of the original.  It won't be a `view` (which `::n` would produce).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One option is to create a boolean index by testing the a range index:

```
import numpy as np
start, step = 2, 3
a[np.arange(len(a)) % step != start]
# array([1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8])
```

You can achieve this similarly in tensorflow using `tf.boolean_mask`:

```
import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.constant([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8])

start, step = 2, 3
mask = ~tf.equal(tf.range(a.shape[-1]) % step, start)

tf.boolean_mask(a, mask).eval()
# array([1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8], dtype=int32)
```

If `a` is ND tensor, you can specify the axis with `boolean_mask`; with 4D tensor *[batch, width, height, channels]* for instance, to select by the fourth axis, i.e the `channels`, you can set `axis=3`:

```
mask = ~tf.equal(tf.range(a.shape[-1]) % step, start)
tf.boolean_mask(a, mask, axis=3)
```

Comment: Only problem left with `tf.boolean_mask` is, that the last dimension is unknown ( `None` ). I used `tensor.set_shape(...)` to solve this (needed to calculate the new shape from the information I had)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [np.delete()](https://het.as.utexas.edu/HET/Software/Numpy/reference/generated/numpy.delete.html) method:

```
>>> np.delete(a, a[1::3])
array([1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8])
```

Remembering that this operation does not modify the original array:

> Return a new array with sub-arrays along an axis deleted. For a one
>   dimensional array, this returns those entries not returned by
>   arr[obj].

Comment: Sorry, my question was ambiguous. I'm only looking for a solution within tensorflow.

Answer (score 1):

A plain application of [numpy.setdiff1d()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.setdiff1d.html) will work for 1D arrays of `int` dtype.

```
In [16]: arr = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8])

In [17]: np.setdiff1d(arr, arr[2::3])
Out[17]: array([1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8])
```

The corresponding TensorFlow equivalent is [`tf.setdiff1d()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/setdiff1d)

---

To handle nD arrays (i.e. tensors), you can first reshape them to 1D arrays, do the selection using `setdiff1d` and then reshape the result back to nD.

Comment: I can't reshape it more down than to two dimensions (because of batching). I will at least have `[batches, channels]` as dimensions. But more importantly my matrices contain real values. `tf.setdiff1d` will not work for that.